# deviance residual plot logistic regressioon

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

For my class project, we are supposed to use fit logistic regression on Framingham data set.

```
fit_select <- glm(Event~Sex+age.group+I(log(Cigar.Day+1))+BP.Med+Prev.Hyp+Diab+ I(log(Tol.Chol))+BMI+Gluc+bp.level, data= data, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

When we try to plot deviance residuals, (and I know that those are supposed to be binomial, but we have over 3000 observations, so by CLT those should behave normally)

```
qqnorm(residuals(fit_select, type = "deviance"))
```

We get 
[image: unexpected output]

What is wrong? I am not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we try to plot deviance residuals, (and I know that those are
>   supposed to be binomial, but we have over 3000 observations, so by CLT
>   those should behave normally)

It should not be normally distributed when you have binary responses. You need count data for get a normal approximation. As I recall correctly, a rough rule of thumb is something an expected count of 5 or greater for binomial and Poisson models.

> What is wrong? I am not sure how to interpret this.

You cannot use the plot for anything when you have binary responses.